# How to test Django CreateView and form_valid

Tags: python, django, testing, django-forms

This maybe very basic but I still fail to understand how to test a Django `CreateView` which has a `form_valid(self, form)` method ?

Here's my code:

```
class NewPatientFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = ['name', 'surname', 'phone', 'email', 'PESEL', 'age',
          'patient_agreement']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.created_by_user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)`
```

I'm using pytest and I simply fail to understand how to test this one. I would be really grateful for a short example how this could be tested ... Thanks!

Comment: The question is: what do you want to test? At what level do you want to develop tests (end-to-end, ...)?

Comment: I would like to test that the form is successfully created, so this form_valid method.

Comment: I'm not sure where your difficulty is. If you want to test that the item is created, then use the test client to post some data to the view, then check the database to verify it has been created, surely?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd have to create the post data and such in the `setUp` of your test.

```
class NewPatientFormTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.form_data = {
            'name': 'Billy',
            'surname': 'Masters',
            'phone': '123-358-2382',
            *...the rest of your form data...*
        }
```

In your `setUp` make sure the rest of your data is setup appropriately. Then use your test - probably something like this:

```
def test_new_patient_form_is_valid(self):
    form = NewPatientForm(data=self.form_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Obviously this is super simplified - but should get you on in the right direction on getting this tested.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed on the lower part? How do you handle the request.user data in the form - THX

Answer (score 1):

Here once again is the class you have:

```
class NewPatientFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = ['name', 'surname', 'phone', 'email', 'PESEL', 'age',
      'patient_agreement']
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.created_by_user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

We can test the form validation by using a [Request Factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/#example):

```
import pytest
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

factory = RequestFactory()

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_form_valid_on_create_view():
    # Arrange
    data = {
       'name': 'Billy',
       'surname': 'Masters',
       'phone': '123-358-2382',
       # other fields
    } 
  
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='jacob', email='jacob@…', password='top_secret')

    request = factory.post( '/[Path to new Patient Form]/', data=data)
    request.user = user
   
    # Act
    response = NewPatientFormView.as_view()(request) # this will submit the form and run the form_valid.  

    # Assert
    
    Assert True
```